# "Move comments to chat"... on request

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

I know that when there are many comments between two users (or when the system "thinks" that comments are becomming "too chatty") the system automatically pops an option to move the discussion to chat. I think that's useful. However, I'd like to know if there's a way to move the messages "on demand".

So, in short, I have a question and a feature proposition:

- Is there a way to move the comments to chat *before* the system pops out the warning?
- If there's not such way, can it be implemented?

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [How can I move a discussion to chat before being prompted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106467), I think.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Oh! Thanks... didn't found it. By the way, I see this feature request has been around a long time... following the link you provided found [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing) on Meta@SE

Comment: Yeah, it's something a lot of people have wanted.